# Posts randomly moved to trash automatically

Tags: wordpress, recycle-bin

Posts randomly moved to trash automatically in Wordpress. When i am restoring posts after some time again they are going to trash automatically. I have deactivated all plugins, does not help. The theme is original, and installed the last version of Wordpress 4.7.3. Also I am using in posts advanced custom fields. Plus what is strange all these posts belong to only one author.

Comment: Check your functions.php file and see if there's anything there. If you're using a child theme, check both function.php files.

Comment: thanks you so much, found the  function ad_expiry() and removed!

Comment: Glad it helped.